# Why can't I access a local variable in extensions? (Xcode 11.4.1)

Tags: xcode

I was writing a code that would allow the user to select a picture from their photo library and display it in an image view. I followed a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yggOGEzueFk). But I can't access my variable while using extensions. In the extension in the imagePickerController function, I cannot choose 'imageView' and I get the error: Use of unresolved identifier 'imageView'. I am certain that they are connected with storyboard very well too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `imageView` is declared inside `addingItemViewController`.

The extension that tries to access that is of `ViewController`.

extension `addingItemViewController` should fix the issue.

**UPDATE**

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] {
```

should be

```
if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
```